# Ipywidget: How to change the widget that is displayed with click of button?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I have the code for the following 2 widgets: one widget that is a plot/slider combination (plot changes when slider is moved) and the other is a dropdown/float combination. I also have the code for two buttons: "Plot/Slider" and "Dropdown/Float".
I would like to combine all this code so that: at any time, the 2 buttons are displayed. And, depending on which button has been clicked, 1 of the 2 widgets is displayed next to the buttons (and all widgets can be interacted with).

For instance, I would like the screen to look like either of these 2 images at all times:

image1:
[image: image 1]
image 2:
[image: image 2]

Would appreciate help with figuring out how to connect/loop my current blocks of code together so that I can switch between widgets at the click of either 2 buttons. Thanks for the help.
Here is the code I currently have for each of the widgets:

BUTTONS CODE:

```
%matplotlib inline

from ipywidgets import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

button1 = Button(description="Plot/Slider")
button2 = Button(description="Dropdown/Float")

buttons = VBox(children=[button1, button2])
all_widgets = HBox(children=[buttons])
display(all_widgets)

def change_widget(b):
    print("*Button Clicked. Widget Changed*")

button1.on_click(change_widget)
button2.on_click(change_widget)
```

PLOT/SLIDER CODE:

```
%matplotlib notebook
from ipywidgets import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def update(w = 1.0):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(w * x))
    fig.canvas.draw()

interact(update)
```

DROPDOWN/FLOAT CODE:

```
from ipywidgets import *

dW = Dropdown(options=['2', '1'])
rW = FloatText(200)
aW = FloatText()

def change_a(_):
    aW.value = int(dW.value) * int(rW.value)

dW.observe(change_a)
rW.observe(change_a)

display(VBox(children=[dW, rW, aW]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually worked on something like this before so we have to close everything and open the other one

```
out = Output()
```

for closing everything:

```
out.clear_output()
```

for displaying the thing you want:

```
with out:        
    display(the thing you want to display)
```